# How to group a column by month as add two additional columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

Image of table that has problem. It didn't keep formatting when i copied it here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JkBJeX2hrDgiFvN3e2pzvJtz_xhbWcw-/view?usp=sharing

I have the current data frame (df5) Im trying to group the dates by month and add the Gross and net. End goal is to plot the gross and net by month over time of the sheet.

The managed this line of code which almost works.

```
per = df5.Date.dt.to_period("M")
g = df5.groupby(per)
df51 = g.sum() 
df51.drop(columns=['Qty', 'Price', 'Cost' ], inplace=True)
df51.head(30)
```

The issue is the Date column isn't in the dataframe.

```
    Gross   Net
Date        
2021-08 4351.50 1351.50
2021-09 6835.00 2035.00
2021-10 4828.00 1628.00
2021-11 5258.50 1608.50
2021-12 4618.00 1418.00
2022-01 6515.50 2015.50 
...
```

Tried this:

```
per = df5.Date.dt.to_period("M")
    g = df5.groupby(per)
    df51 = g.sum() 
    df51.drop(columns=['Qty', 'Price', 'Cost' ], inplace=True)
    df51.head(30)
```

Expected:

```
Date    Gross   Net     
2021-08 4351.50 1351.50
2021-09 6835.00 2035.00
2021-10 4828.00 1628.00
2021-11 5258.50 1608.50
2021-12 4618.00 1418.00
2022-01 6515.50 2015.50
...
```

The date seems to be outside the data frame and will not show up when calling the headers ect.

Comment: So I am trying to group all the sales by month and sum the gross and net profits. Everything I have got to work does not keep the date in the data frame which is needed to graph by data. The data sets will change so I wont be able to assign months to every row. it would not be practical. My lates code below is is cleaner but still results in the same issue. 

df5['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['Date'], format='%y%m%d')
df5 = df5.groupby(df5['Date'].dt.to_period('m')).sum()
print(df5)

Comment: Updates with image of DF im getting

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should solve your question. You can edit 1 column like this.

```
df["date"] = df["date"].dt.to_period()
df = df.groupby(by=["per"]).sum()
```